# Unity3D Game Crashes in Xcode 9 - iOS 11

Tags: iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, ios11, xcode9

Today I launched fully working Unity3D game in Xcode 9, iPhone 6 running iOS 11. Its crashing on launch.

Every time crashing in same function : SetupMetalFBO

Here is console log:

```
validateRenderPassDescriptor:487: failed assertion `Texture at colorAttachment[0] has usage (0x01) which doesn't specify MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget (0x04)'
```

[image]

Same code worked perfect with Xcode 8.3.3 iOS 10.

How to fix crash in Xcode 9 ?

---

**UPDATES_SOLUTION** :

Solution is simple, just goto Xcode->Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme, disable Metal API Validation. This fix crash.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget` in the error shows that this is a Apple's Metal issue.

Unity 4.6.9 is extremely old to work on iOS 11 and is no longer patched to fix issues on platforms like iOS. You should also worry about your latest app being rejected from the app store due to IPv6 compatibly issues.

You have three options:

**1**.Disable Metal API Validation in Xcode

**2**.Use OpenGLES instead of Metal.

First of all, disable Auto Graphics API then change iOS Graphics API to OpenGLES2 or OpenGLES3 in Unity's Player Settings.

[image]

**3**.Update to Unity to the latest version of Unity if **#1** and **#2** fail. If you update Unity and the problem is still there then you can file for bug report from the Editor. I expect this issue to be gone if you update Unity.

Comment: one good thing is, when I archive ipa and then install it to device then works perfect. So apple may approve..let me check your solution soon.

Comment: I've seen so many rejected due to IPv6  issue even if they worked on the device. It depends on which API you use or maybe Unity decided to patch 4.6 version to fix the Apple rejection issue.

Comment: Solution 1 worked. I just disabled Metal API Validation in Xcode. Thanks a lot for quick answer.

Comment: IPv6 issue means? last week my Unity3D 4.6.9 game approved..uploaded with Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: See [this](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/05/10/unity-and-ipv6-support/)  and [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-ios-and-ipv6-support.404938/page-2#post-2691522). Don't worry about if your app was accepted. Glad I was able to help.